# How to compare two number whne extracting

Tags: imacros

I'm extracting numbers from web page, and i want compare them, if 
number is more than [previous one, then show it in iimDispaly(), otherwise if is it lower then skip, i trued here to do but cannot find a solution.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {

for(var j = 3; j<=33; j+=3 ) {

iimPlayCode('TAG POS='+j+' TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"group_row_labeled" EXTRACT=TXT')
var res = iimGetLastExtract();
var result = res.replace(/[а-z]/g, '');

if(j==3) {
    var firstRes = result;
}

if(result => firstRes) {
    iimDisplay("Highest Number: " + result)
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy & paste the following code and try to play it:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {

for(var j = 3; j<=33; j+=3 ) {

iimPlayCode('TAG POS='+j+' TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"group_row_labeled" EXTRACT=TXT')
var res = iimGetLastExtract();
var result = parseFloat(res.replace(/[a-z]/g, ''));

if(j==3) {
    var firstRes = result;
}

if(result >= firstRes) {
    iimDisplay("Highest Number: " + result)
}
}
}
```